# How to extract values from user input form via custom middleware?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I tried to find thoes values with debugger in `HttpContext` but it seems like it's more complicated than just `Dictionary(key,value)`

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    foreach (var item in context.???)
    {
        Console.WriteLine('{item.Key}':'{item.Value}'");
    }
    await next.Invoke();
});
```

e.g

Sample form:

```
<input type="text" name="FirstName" />
<input type="text" name="Age" />
```

Expected console output:

```
'FirstName':'John'
'Age':'123'
```

Comment: Any reason you aren't using a Controller? You could even use an ActionFilter for this

Comment: for form stuff... context.Request.Form items

Comment: @Clay Please write it as answer. Imma accept.

Comment: @Joelty - okay, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The place to go for form data is context.Request.Form. If you want query string data parsed out, it would be context.Request.Query...but the form data is what you need.